# Read specific column in text file using C#

Tags: c#

I have a column based txt file. How can I read any specific column programmatically?

So far I came up with this solution where it reads the specified column index for example: firstValue[0] will read all the (1) in the text file.

If I write it like this then I'll be able to read the first three index fine, but there has to be a cleaner approach.

> Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", firstValue[0], firstValue[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdWMZ.png), firstValue[2], firstValue[3]));

If there was a way I could count the columns in the text file than pick the index of the column I want to read; that would be ideal.

I would like to read:
121
122
123
124

> I've searched online for a similar problem, but they didn't quite have what I wanted.

```
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(YourFile);
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var firstValue = line.Split(new string[] { "        " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];                
            Console.WriteLine(firstValue[0]);
            //Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", firstValue[0], firstValue[1], firstValue[2], firstValue[3]));
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
```

[image]

Comment: When your columns have fixed length you can set positionpointer to beginning of your column. Or you can parse string into array and use only one element.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll research how that is done @Findus

Comment: If the space character is your delimiter, use that, don't repeat it. `"123 456    789               1111".Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` => `string[4] { "123", "456", "789", "1111" }`

Comment: You can't see it in my comment, but there are multiple spaces between the columns...: "123_456____789_______________111"

Comment: Got it, that makes sence. Thanks @BurnsBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, splitting it like like this:

```
var firstValue = line.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

`firstValue` would equal a concatenated string something like this `121     20412           010` in the foreach loop

[image]

---

So then I tried another approach which was:

```
var firstValue = line.Split(new string[] { "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Which indexed the columns, so I can choose which column I want the data to come from.

```
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var firstValue = line.Split(new string[] { "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            Console.WriteLine(firstValue[2]);                
        }
```

Output:

> 010
>
> 020
>
> 030
>
> 040

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
public static List<string> GetColumnValues(string[] lines, int columnNumber)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    Regex regex = new Regex("[ ]{2,}", RegexOptions.None);
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        var cleanedLine = regex.Replace(line, " ");
        var columns = line.Split(" ", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        result.Add(columns[columnNumber-1]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Additional checks should be added, but you can get an idea.